# Address ID of dynamically generated Input to send value via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all, Hello Everyone, I'm new in here.
I have searched all over the site and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem...

I have an input, being generated via AJAX-PHP dynamically, and I want the user to enter some Value there, then send the data via Ajax for processing it into Mysql.

Thing is, javascript is reading the input value of the as Null:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Here's the code:

```js
function addBandMember() {
  var Btn = _("addBandMem");
  var errorMsg = _("UpWinMsg");
  var url = window.location.href;
  var mmbr = _("#newBandMember").value; // <-THIS IS RETURNING NULL
  if (mmbr == "") {
    errorMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a USERNAME";
  } else {
    errormsg.innerHTML = "please wait...";
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", url);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
        //SETTINGS RECEIVED
        if (ajax.responseText != "member_added") {
          errorMsg.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        } else {
          toggleUpWin();
          receiveUserData();
        }
      }
    };
    ajax.send("mmbr=" + mmbr);
  }
}
```

I believe this is happening because the Input field is being generated AFTER the document loads, via Ajax and PHP... Am I wrong? How can I address this newly-generated ID?

Thanks!

Comment: I can help you with jquery,but I am pretty weak with javascript ajax

Comment: Replace your line number 5 var mmbr = _("#newBandMember").value;  , with this var mmbr = _("#newBandMember").val();

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to get the value of input box.

```
var mmbr =$("#newBandMember").val();
```

OR

```
var mmbr =_("#newBandMember").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... It was just a stupid mistake...

I have a function set for "getElementById" which requires a string, without "#".

so it'd be:

```
var mmbr = _("newBandMember").value; // <-THIS IS NOT RETURNING NULL
```

instead of:

```
var mmbr = _("#newBandMember").value; // <-THIS IS RETURNING NULL
```

Thanks to everyone who answered!